# Secondary DNS Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7

We have two Domain Controllers configured in our environment. When I do ipconfig/ all, I see the primary under the primary but the secondary is not there. Both are Global Catalog servers, the primary points to itself for DNS and the secondary points to the primary.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IP details you see via ipconfig /all are either set manually on your machine or via DHCP.

- If they're set manually, well...add a second DNS server manually too.
- If they're set via DHCP then change the scope to hand out two DNS servers.

It's likely to be as simple as that.